# Render Component Only Once in a Div Below an LI When In-Line Button is Clicked

Tags: reactjs

Currently, this will render a  component below each of the list items when the img is clicked by keeping an array of shown components per index in local state.  Eg. (state.showItems ==[true,false,false,true]).

I would like to restrict the values in this array to only one 'true' at a time so that the `<SuggestStep />` component is rendered only once in the div under  the button that was clicked.  I'm not using CSS because the list can grow very large and don't want to render and hide a component for each one.  Also considered using a radio button displayed as an image, but don't know if that would involve mixing forms with LI's and if that is bad. Feedback on the question of restricting the `showItems` array items to only one true at a time, and general patterns to approaching the component rendering problem I'm describing are welcome.

```
class CurrentSteps extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          toggleOnSuggestInput: false,
          showItems: []
    }
      this.clickHandler = this.clickHandler.bind(this)
    }

    clickHandler(index){
      let showItems = this.state.showItems.slice();
      showItems[index] = !showItems[index]
      this.setState({showItems})
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        toggleOnSuggestInput: !prevState.toggleOnSuggestInput
      }))
    }

      render() {

      let steps = this.props.currentGoalSteps.map((step, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={`divKey${index}`}>
              <li key={index}>{step}</li>
              <img  key={`imageKey${index}`} onClick={this.clickHandler.bind(this,index)} alt="" src={plus}/>
              {this.state.showItems[index] ? <SuggestStep /> : null}
            </div>
                )
            });

    return (
             <div>
            <ul> {steps} </ul>
             </div>
    )
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making the following modifications to your code...

Change your `this.state` like so.

```
this.state = {
    toggleOnSuggestInput: false,
    activeIndex: null
};
```

Change your `clickHandler` to this.

```
clickHandler(event, index) {
    this.setState({ activeIndex: index })
}
```

Change your `map` to like the one below. Notice the `onClick` prop change.

```
let steps = this.props.currentGoalSteps.map((step, index) => {
    return (
        <div key={`divKey${index}`}>
            <li key={index}>
                {step}
            </li>
            <img
                key={`imageKey${index}`}
                onClick={e => this.clickHandler(e, index)}
                alt=""
                src={plus}
            />
            {this.state.activeIndex === index ? <SuggestStep /> : null}
        </div>
    );
});
```

Comment: Sure enough this seems to work brilliantly with text, although for some reason after the initial click my component <SuggestStep />  fails to load silently on subsequent clicks .

Comment: what do you mean by silently?

Comment: By silently I mean I see no errors in the console while rendering of <SuggestStep />  hangs

Comment: That's what I'm saying, there is no error. On the second click, I only see my 'loading...' placeholder where <SuggestStep /> should be

Comment: But replacing <SuggestStep /> with <p>Bob</p> work fine.  Hence why I'm overall pleased with the answer...

Comment: hmmmm I see, that is strange, can you send me some context for the `SuggestStep` component? I'm curious as to why it isnt loading in. Id like to get you through the issue.

Comment: Can do. Thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151222/discussion-between-canaan-seaton-and-zach-is-my-name).